# How can I do insert a new record to an associative table about each existing data by using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Environment: python3.7, SQLAlchemy1.3, SQLite3.22

I defined 2 tables and 1 associative table like below.

```
# associative table
taggings = Table('taggings', Base.metadata, 
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('articles.id'), nullable=False),
    Column('tag_name', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.name'), nullable=False),
)

# mapper about article master
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=taggings, backref='articles')

# mapper about tag master
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

Now I want to be able to create new article which tagged with any existing tags.
So, I tried like...

```
new_one = Article(**payload.article)
new_one.tags = [Tag(name=x) for x in payload.tags]  # these tags are already stored in database.
sesion.add(new_one)
session.flush()
```

And test it, but I got an error about UNIQUE constraint. 
Detail is here.

> *** sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: tags.name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES (?)'] [parameters: (('x',), ('a',))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

I guess `session.add` always attempt to insert when parent element has children, and the "children" which presented here is maybe `Tag`.
But I really want to do is only create new records against `taggings` table referencing new article data and any existing tags.

I read about [cascade in the official document](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.cascade), and I tried removing `save-update` option from `relationship()` but not resolved.

Please how to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that you're creating tags that are already existing in the database. Can you just look into the DB (or print in the code) to see if you are not trying to create the same tags (as long as the name of the tag is the primary key so it should be unique)?

Comment: Ah yes, tags are existing.  
I wander creating new article with existing tags via `session.add`.
So can I do it by using SQLAlchemy?

I know I can create associative records to `taggings` table explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

Considering your response to my question, you should add checking if the tag from the `payload` isn't already in the database. So it should be something like this:

```
new_one = Article(**payload.article)
tags = []
for tag_name in payload.tags:
    tag = session.query(Tag).filter_by(name=tag_name).first()
    # tag will be None if it does not exist in the database
    tags.append(tag if tag else Tag(name=tag_name))
new_one.tags = tags
sesion.add(new_one)
session.flush()
```

So now you'll be using the existing tag if it's already in the database or create a new one if it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see that I am required existing checking.

Comment: But this way looks making reduce performance by checking every tag.
I want to write this process like below.

1. Run `insert or ignore` sql for passed tags. 
2. Create new article instance.
3. Add tags to `.tags` of the article instance.
4. Flush new article to database.

Then 4, I think it will run just 2 queries.

1. create article
2. bulk create taggings

Now I understood it can't via appending collection.

And sorry for my poor english...